# how do I set up an if statement

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How would I go about setting up an if statement using only the following bitwise operations:

- !
- ~
- &
- ^
- |
- +
- <<
- >>

As an example: **"if x is negative then add 15"**

This would mean that if the input was `x = 0xF0000000`, then we would produce `0xF000000F`. If the input was `x = 0x00000004`, we would produce `0x00000004`.

Comment: You might want to change the title to something like: "How to conditionally add 15 using bitwise operators"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `15` to a number if it is negative, and `0` otherwise as follows. Shifting a negative number right will shift in 1's if the value is negative, and 0's otherwise. Shifting by 31 will fill the int with either 1's or 0's. ANDing by `0xF` will set the summand to 15 if it is negative, and 0 otherwise, resulting in no change to `x`.

```
x += (x >> 31) & 0xF;
```

If you're worried about the implementation dependent behavior of shifting a signed number to the right. You can do the same thing with the following code, however you still are depending on a two's complement representation of the number. The shift results in `0` or `1`, the multiplication scales the number to the appropriate value.

```
 x += (((unsigned)x >> 31) * 0xF);
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true - right shifting a signed number is implementation dependent. In most cases it will likely work though.

Comment: @JasonD, True, however the underlying representation of signed numbers is also implementation dependent. And to answer this question with bit manipulation as asked, that is going to need to be leveraged.

Comment: @JasonD, I've added a variant that doesn't take advantage of the arithmetic shift behavior.

Comment: Yeah, but now you've used a multiply :)  (You could do `x + ((~(((unsigned)x >> 31)-1))&15)`); but I'm being needlessly pedantic.

Comment: @JasonD, There are some really cool bit manipulation techniques using the properties of binary multiplication. I honestly never understood the need to exclude arithmetic operations from questions regarding bitwise operations, they resolve to instructions that modify bits in different ways, just the same. But yes you could, thanks for pointing it out. :)